# Pandas.read_csv(,parse_dates,) forces to make a column of float data into string

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I tried to read a csv file

[image: Test.csv]

using

```
df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv',index_col=0,parse_dates=[0],header=None,names=['Open','Close','High','Low','Vol','Mon'])
df['Open']
```

But for unknown reason the result of column 'Open' is a list of string data. The other columns such as 'High' 'Low' are fine, just the 'Open' is wrong. So I tried add `dtype=float`at the end.

[image: 1]

Still the data of 'Open' are string. And I figured out it's the problem of `parse_dates` cause without it it's fine.

[image: without parse_dates]

But I still need to make date's type datetime64 so I have to do

```
df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv',index_col=[0],header=None,names=['Open','Close','High','Low','Vol','Mon'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df['Open']
```

to make things right. But I wonder what causes it? it seems to be a bug to me. So I post it out see if anyone had seen the same problem.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, text, data. They should be listed inside the question itself.

Comment: Try `parse_dates=True`. This way pandas will try to parse index by default and see if that help at all.

Comment: @ThuYeinTun Sorry I didn't know that. Will try that next time

Comment: @pavel thanks, if using  `parse_dates=True` it woks. tho sometimes I may need to specify which column to be converted to datetime64 type, But i think in most cases ==True would just do the work, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using `df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv',infer_date_format=True,...)` from the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv). Also, in the same section under the `dtype` option it looks like you can pass converter functions, so perhaps also try:

> df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv', dtype={'Open': pd.to_datetime},...)`

Not sure the underlying reason, without the text pasted to somewhere like bpaste.net i cant test it.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately still not working. I'm new to python so I'm still learning. Sometimes things are tricky to me. I just tried type `df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv',names=['Open','Close','High','Low','Vol','Mon'])` turns out i don't nee to `type index_col=0` and `header=None` then I tried `df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv',parse_dates=True,names=['Open','Close','High','Low','Vol','Mon'])` which works fine so I guess i will be using this if nothing wrong happens in the future. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: sorry I didn't know how to accept answer so i come back and late check it